# Mathematica StringReplace to replace a substring containing newlines

Tags: regex, string, wolfram-mathematica

I have something like the following in a string:

```
blah blah

BEGINIGNORE
   this stuff should get stripped out
ENDIGNORE

more stuff here
```

I would like to do this (perl syntax): s/BEGINIGNORE.*ENDIGNORE//s -- namely, strip out everything between BEGINIGNORE and ENDIGNORE, inclusive.
You would think the following would do that in Mathematica:

```
StringReplace[str, re["BEGINIGNORE[.\\s]*ENDIGNORE"]->""]
```

But it doesn't.  How do I do this in Mathematica?

PS: I define the following alias:  `re = RegularExpression;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the `(?s)` modifier in the regex.  That's equivalent to Perl's `/s` modifier and is part of standard [PCRE](http://pcre.org) syntax.

```
StringReplace[str, re["BEGINIGNORE(?s).*ENDIGNORE"]->""]
```

More details in this answer to a related question:
[Bug in Mathematica: regular expression applied to very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257884/bug-in-mathematica-regular-expression-applied-to-very-long-string/2261807#2261807)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that for some reason "`[.\\s]`" and "`[.\\n]`" don't work but "`(.|\\n)`" does.  So the following works:

```
strip[s_String] := StringReplace[s, re@"BEGINIGNORE(.|\\n)*ENDIGNORE" -> ""]
```

Comment: The reason is that "[.\s]" (inside square brackets) matches a dot, a slash, or an "s", whereas "(.|\n)" matches any character except a newline (the dot) or a newline (the "\n"), which is what you want,

Comment: I see. Thanks Markus!  (I did confirm that in Perl this works the way I had expected, which I think is the more reasonable behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
StringReplace[str, re["BEGINIGNORE(.|\\n)*ENDIGNORE"]->""]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you followed up, you need parens rather than square brackets around the expression that you wanted to `*`.

The square brackets define a character class here, as in most regular expression languages.  That's why `[.\\s]` isn't working as you expected, it stands for a set of characters rather than a parenthesized expression.  Maybe the Mathematica use of [] for expressions got you thinking in that direction?

Comment: Actually, in Perl it works as I expected so I do blame Mathematica here.