# Mathematica regular expressions on unicode strings

Tags: regex, debugging, wolfram-mathematica, pcre, character-properties

This was a fascinating debugging experience.
Can you spot the difference between the following two lines?

```
StringReplace["–", RegularExpression@"[\\s\\S]" -> "abc"]
StringReplace["-", RegularExpression@"[\\s\\S]" -> "abc"]
```

They do very different things when you evaluate them.  It turns out it's because the string being replaced in the first line consists of a unicode en dash, as opposed to a plain old ascii dash in the second line.

In the case of the unicode string, the regular expression doesn't match.
I meant the regex "[\s\S]" to mean "match any character (including newline)" but Mathematica apparently treats it as "match any *ascii* character".

How can I fix the regular expression so the first line above evaluates the same as the second?  Alternatively, is there an asciify filter I can apply to the strings first?

PS: The Mathematica documentation says that its string pattern matching is built on top of the Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions library (http://pcre.org) so the problem I'm having may not be specific to Mathematica.

Comment: I don't know why this old question popped up as active, but the issue seems to have been resolved by version 10, both work now. unicode en dash is keyed as  "\:2013" in mathematica btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an asciify function which I used as a workaround at first:

```
f[s_String] := s
f[x_] := FromCharacterCode[x]

asciify[s_String] := 
  StringJoin[f /@ (ToCharacterCode[s] /. x_?(#>255&) :> "&"<>ToString[x]<>";")]
```

Then I realized, thanks to @Isaac's answer, that "." as a regular expression doesn't seem to have this unicode problem.  I learned from the answers to [Bug in Mathematica: regular expression applied to very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257884/bug-in-ma) that "(.|\n)" is ill-advised but that "(?s)." is recommended.  So I think the best fix is the following:

```
StringReplace["–", RegularExpression@"(?s)." -> "abc"]
```

Comment: Interesting reading in the other question/answers you site.  Given what's there, I'm inclined to agree that `"(?s)."` is probably better, though as I read those answers, the issue may be limited to `"(.|\n)*"` (with the `*`).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `StringExpression` in place of `RegularExpression`. This works as desired:

```
f[s_String] := StringReplace[s, _ -> "abc"]
```

In a `StringExpression`, `Blank[]` will match anything, including non-ASCII characters.

**EDIT** in response to version updates: as of *Mathematica* 11.0.1, it looks like letter characters with character codes up to `2^16 - 1` (which is called out as the maximum value for [`FromCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCharacterCode.html)), the results of `StringMatchQ[LetterCharacter]` now match those of `LetterQ`.

```
AllTrue[FromCharacterCode /@ Range[2^16 - 1], 
 LetterQ@# === StringMatchQ[#, LetterCharacter] &]
(* True *)
```

Comment: As noted in the Working with String Patterns tutorial [1] under "RegularExpression versus StringExpression", the string pattern `_` and `RegularExpression["(?s)."]` are equivalent.

[1] http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `"(.|\n)"` for the input to RegularExpression seems to work for me.  The pattern matches `.` (any non-newline character) or `\n` (a newline character).